# Prove $\operatorname{span}(S)=\operatorname{span}(S')$

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Theorem.** If $S=\{\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2,\dots,\mathbf v_r\}$ and $S'=\{\mathbf w_1,\mathbf w_2,\dots,\mathbf w_k\}$ are nonempty sets of vectors in a vector space $V$, then
>   $$
> \operatorname{span}\{\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2,\dots,\mathbf v_r\} =
> \operatorname{span}\{\mathbf w_1,\mathbf w_2,\dots,\mathbf w_k\}
> $$
>   if and only if each vector in $S$ is a linear combination of those in $S'$, and each vector in $S'$ is a linear combination of those in $S$.

I am not really sure how to prove this theorem.  I know that if $S$ is a linear combination of $S'$, then $S=span(S')$.

If $S'$ is a linear combination of $S$, then $S'=span(S)$.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $span(S')=span(S)$.  Then in particular, since the elements of $S$ are in $span(S)=spans(S')$, it follows that the elements of $S$ are in $span(S')$, and thus the elements of $S$ can be expressed as the linear combinations of elements of $S'$ by definition of being in $span(S')$.  Similarly, the elements of $S'$ can be expressed as linear combinations of elements in $S$.  Thus, we have our first direction:

Now the second direction, showing that if each element of $S$ can be written as a linear combination of elements in $S'$, and vice-a-versa, then $span(S)=span(S')$.  Linear combinations of linear combinations of the elements of $S$ are just linear combinations of $S$: $$\sum_{i}{a_i\left(\sum_{j}{b_{ij}s_j}\right)}=\sum_{i}{\sum_{j}{a_ib_{ij}s_j}}=\sum_{j}{\left(\sum_i{a_ib_{ij}}\right)s_j}$$ so that since each element of $S$ lies in $span(S')$, we see that $span(S)\subset span(S')$.  But the above analogously shows that $span(S')\subset span(S)$ since $S'$ satisfies the same condition as $S$, from which we see that $span(S)=span(S')$. (Since $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$ implies that $A=B$)

Comment: In the second sentence, did you mean: the elements in $S'$ are in $span(S)$?

Comment: No, I said that the elements of $S$ are in $span(S)$ (this holds true always), but I then implicitely used the fact that $span(S)=span(S')$ to say that the elements of $S$ are in $span(S')$.  I'll clarify that.

Comment: Why does it always hold that the elements in $S$ are in $span(S)$?

Comment: $s=1s+\sum_{t\in S, t\neq s}{0t}$.  When $S$ is infinite you just need to check that the latter summation is a finite one, but it doesn't really make much difference since they're all zero.

Comment: I don't really understand that. What is $s$?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  $s$ is any element of $S$.

Comment: Since $S$ can be represented as linear combinations of elements in itself, does this mean that $S$ is linearly dependent?

Comment: No, a set $S$ is said to be linearly dependent if there is an element of $S$ that can be written as a linear combination of the *remaining* elements (i.e. not including itself).  The linear combination I gave involved $s$, it does not fulfill the requirement.

Comment: Hello, I came back to this question to review.  I realize I am not understanding the second direction.  Is it possible to explain a little more? thanks

Comment: @Lanfranco hopefully the changes I made above help out.  let me know if there's anything more you don't get.

Answer (score 1):

A vector is in the span of $S'$ so that $v=a_1w_1+a_2w_2+...+a_kw_k$

Each vector in $S'$ is a linear combination of those in $S$

$w_1=b_{11}v_1+b_{12} v_2+...+b_{1k} v_k$

$w_2=b_{21}v_1+b_{22} v_2+...+b_{2k} v_k$

...

$w_k=b_{k1}v_1+b_{k2} v_2+...+b_{kk} v_k$

So $v$ can be represented as

$v = a_1(b_{11}v_1+b_{12} v_2+...+b_{1k} v_k)+a_2(b_{21}v_1+b_{22} v_2+...+b_{2k} v_k)+...$

This shows that every vector in $S'$ is in $S$, and a similar process shows that every element in $S$ is in $S'$ which means $\text{span}(S)=\text{span}(S')$

Comment: How does this show that every vector in $S'$ is in $S$?

Comment: Does that singular $v$ represent an arbitrary vector in $S$?

Comment: v is an arbitrary vector in $S'$. In the last line, you can rearrange everything to get $v=(a_1b_{11}+a_2b_{21}+...)v_1+(a_2b_{21}+a_2b_{22}+...)v_2+...$ which shows that is the representation of v in $S$, which means that v is in the span of $S$.